# How can I use a data-attr within a href instead of an id?

Tags: html

Lets say I have this html in the body element:

`<a href="#fragment-1">Go to href</a>`

And I need that anchor to take me to this other element within the same page:

`<div id="fragment-1">Some content</div>`

There I am doing it with an `id`, but I would like to use a data-attribute.

Like this anchor: `<a href="data-attr">Go to href</a>`

taking to this `div`: `<div data-attr="fragment-1">Some content</div>`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Can't do it with straight HTML. You'd need JavaScript.

Comment: Also, why would you need that? IDs should be unique, so there shouldn't be a problem using `#fragment-1`. `data-attr` may not be unique.

Comment: @BenM exactly, because I need some other elements depending on `fragments-X`. I need to have more than 1 element with the same thing. And it could not be a class.

Comment: @TheUnnamed But a single anchor element can only link to one item at a time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Since data attributes

- are user-defined, and
- don't have uniqueness semantics built into them,

they can't act like IDs for the purposes of anchors.

You could use JavaScript to scroll the page to whichever element matches `document.querySelector('[data-attr="your-fragment"]')`, but that's JavaScript territory. You won't get this behavior for free in HTML itself.